# Form upload 404 error in Open Data Kit

Tags: odk

I am working on a project and needed to collect data using open data kit. I have created a server using google app engine, but when uploading the form to the aggregate server, I get this error:

> sample-Error: Not Found (404) at 
>   http://odkproject- 207015.appspot.com/ODKAggregate/submission?deviceID=imei%3A864898033928120

Answer (score 0):

404 is returned if the form you're submiting is does not exist on the server.

You have to delete all forms and load them back. 
Hope it fixes your issue.